# Problem with parent-child class and turtle, kernel says it is an error in the turtle bib

Tags: python, parent-child, turtle-graphics

Below is the code I have and the error which is displayed is:  turtle.Vec2D() argument after * must be an iterable, not int.

The task is to create a square, triangle, polygon and rectangle. The properties should be put together in a parent class. Each other class should be the child class from the class `GeometricObject` (the parent class).

```py
import math
import turtle

        
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
class GeometricObject: 
    def __init__(self, starting_angle = 45, side_length = 100, position = (0,0)): 
        self.side_length = side_length 
        self.starting_angle = starting_angle 
        self.position = position
        
class Square(GeometricObject):
    def __init__(self, side_length, position, starting_angle, turn = 90):
        super().__init__(side_length, position, starting_angle)
        self.turn = turn 
        
    def draw(self):
        turtle.setheading(self.starting_angle)
        self.move_to_position(self.position)

        for i in range(4): 
            turtle.forward(self.side_length)
            turtle.left(self.turn)
        self.starting_angle = 0
        turtle.setheading(0)
            
        
    def calculate_area(self): 
        return math.sqrt(self.side_length)
        
    def move_to_position(self, new_position = (100, 0)): 
        turtle.penup() 
        turtle.goto(new_position)
        turtle.pendown()
        
    
    def set_starting_angle(self, starting_angle = 45): 
        self.starting_angle = starting_angle
        
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
#------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Rectangle(GeometricObject):
    
    def __init__(self, side_length, position, starting_angle, width = 100):
        super().__init__(side_length, position, starting_angle)
        self.width = width
    
    def draw(self):
        turtle.setheading(self.starting_angle)
        self.move_to_position(self.position)
        for i in range(2): 
            turtle.forward(self.side_length)
            turtle.left(90)
            turtle.forward(self.width)
            turtle.left(90)
        self.starting_angle = 0
        turtle.setheading(0) 
    def move_to_position(self, new_position = (0, 0)): 
         turtle.penup() 
         turtle.goto(new_position)
         turtle.pendown()
    
        
            
    def calculate_area(self):
        print(self.side_length * self.width)
    def set_starting_angle(self, starting_angle = 45): 
        self.starting_angle = starting_angle
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
#------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Triangle(GeometricObject):
    def __init__(self, side_length, position, starting_angle):
        super().__init__(side_length, position, starting_angle)

        pass
    
    def draw(self):
        turtle.setheading(self.starting_angle)
        self.move_to_position(self.position)

        for i in range(3): 
            turtle.forward(self.side_length)
            turtle.left(120)
        self.starting_angle = 0
        turtle.setheading(0) 
    def move_to_position(self, new_position = (100, 0)): 
         turtle.penup() 
         turtle.goto(new_position)
         turtle.pendown()
            
    def calculate_area(self): 
        print(self.side_length * (self.side_length / 2))
    def set_starting_angle(self, starting_angle): 
        self.starting_angle = starting_angle
        

        
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
#------------------------------------------------------------------------

class RegularPolygon(GeometricObject):
    def __init__(self, side_length, position, starting_angle, n = 6):
        super().__init__(side_length, position, starting_angle)
        self.n = n
    
    def draw(self):
        turtle.setheading(self.starting_angle)
        self.move_to_position(self.position)

        for i in range(self.n): 
            turtle.forward(self.side_length)
            turtle.left(360 / self.n)
            
        self.starting_angle = 0
        turtle.setheading(0) 
    def move_to_position(self, new_position = (100, 0)): 
         turtle.penup() 
         turtle.goto(new_position)
         turtle.pendown()
            
    def calculate_area(self): 
        #print((3 * math.sqrt(3) * (self.side_length **2)) / 2)
        print((self.n / 4) * math.cot(180 / self.n) * math.sqrt(self.side_length))
        
    def set_starting_angle(self, starting_angle = 45): 
        self.starting_angle = starting_angle
    

        
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
#------------------------------------------------------------------------

def main():
    # ----- IGNORE THIS PART ---------------------------------
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    rootwindow = wn.getcanvas().winfo_toplevel()
    rootwindow.call('wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', '1')
    rootwindow.call('wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', '0')
    # ----- IGNORE THIS PART ---------------------------------
    
    rect1 = Rectangle(60, (0,0), 45)
    rect1.set_starting_angle(90)
    rect1.draw()
    square1 = Square(60, (100, 200), 45)
    square1.set_starting_angle(45)
    square1.draw()
    regpol= RegularPolygon()
    regpol.set_starting_angle(180)
    regpol.draw()
    tri = Triangle()
    tri.set_starting_angle(239)
    tri.draw()
    
    wn.mainloop()
    turtle.done()
    
main()
```

I wanted turtle to draw all of the objects I created.

Comment: What line is the error on? A [mcve] is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that you're playing fast and loose with argument order:

```
class GeometricObject: 
    def __init__(self, starting_angle = 45, side_length = 100, position = (0,0)): 
        
class Square(GeometricObject):
    def __init__(self, side_length, position, starting_angle, turn = 90):
    super().__init__(side_length, position, starting_angle)

class Rectangle(GeometricObject):
    def __init__(self, side_length, position, starting_angle, width = 100):
    super().__init__(side_length, position, starting_angle)
```

Since these classes are calling the `super.__init__()` of `GeometricObject`, their arguments should match order-wise.  A simple fix might be:

```
class GeometricObject: 
    def __init__(self, side_length=100, position=(0,0), starting_angle=45):
```

Which would get you further along until you break on this call:

```
regpol = RegularPolygon()
```

which is lacking required arguments.